# Split a string column, based on regex matching in pyspark or koalas

Tags: python, regex, dataframe, pyspark

### The Problem:

I am trying to process a string column which has mixed nature of data. Besides I've tried a few things in Pandas, however uses a lot of memory and that's where I wish to switch to Koalas or Spark.

### The Data:

So assume this is my Dataframe:

| duration | Class |
| --- | --- |
| 00:00:09 | AAB |
| 00:00:08 | AAB |
| 00:37:55 | AAB |
| 00:10:20 | AAB |
| 00:18:29 | AAB |
| 00:18:20 | AAB |
| 00:10:41 | AAB |
| 00:18:20 | AAB |
| 00:16:29 | AAB |
| 00:08:09 | AAB |
| 00:18:19 | AAB |
| 00:01:39 | AAB |
| 1 | RRE |
| 1 | RRE |
| 234 | ILL |
| 452 | INL |
| 11220 | INL |
| 100 | AAB |
| 122 | AAB |
| 00:18:29 | BRQ |
| 1 | BRQ |
| 2 | AKK |
| 8 | AKK |

The `duration` is something I couldn't get through even in Pandas using different regex. This column is a mixture of Time (HH:MM:SS) and Data unit (in KBs) which I have to split into 2 separate columns i.e. `call_duration` and `data` respectively.

### My Failed Attempts

I tried writing this using Koalas, however it doesn't split the Time data and Internet Data unit from that column.

```
ks_preprocess_df["Duration"].str.split(r'^(?=\d\d\:\d\d\:\d\d\n)(?!.*[-])')

ks_preprocess_df["Duration"].str.split(r'^[?=\d+:\d+:\d\d\n][?]')

ks_preprocess_df["Duration"].str.split(r'\d\d\:\d\d\:\d\d\n', expand=True)
```

### The Expected Output:

| data | call_duration | Class |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 00:00:09 | AAB |
| 0 | 00:00:08 | AAB |
| 0 | 00:37:55 | AAB |
| 0 | 00:10:20 | AAB |
| 0 | 00:18:29 | AAB |
| 0 | 00:18:20 | AAB |
| 0 | 00:10:41 | AAB |
| 0 | 00:18:20 | AAB |
| 0 | 00:16:29 | AAB |
| 0 | 00:08:09 | AAB |
| 0 | 00:18:19 | AAB |
| 0 | 00:01:39 | AAB |
| 1 | null | RRE |
| 1 | null | RRE |
| 234 | null | ILL |
| 452 | null | INL |
| 11220 | null | INL |
| 100 | null | AAB |
| 122 | null | AAB |
| 0 | 00:18:29 | BRQ |
| 1 | null | BRQ |
| 2 | null | AKK |
| 8 | null | AKK |

Comment: What did you try in Pandas?

Comment: @JackTaylor Because I am more familiar to it than PySpark or Koalas

Comment: No, _what_ did you try in Pandas? What code was causing you memory problems?

Comment: Ohh Sorry, I tried those same things as I did in Koalas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pyspark you can use `rlike` with `when` expression :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = df.withColumn(
    "data",
    F.when(F.col("duration").rlike("^[0-9]*$"), F.col("duration")).otherwise(0)
).withColumn(
    "call_duration",
    F.when(F.col("duration").rlike(r"^*\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$"), F.col("duration"))
).select(
    "data", "call_duration", "Class"
)

df1.show(20)

#+-----+-------------+-----+
#| data|call_duration|Class|
#+-----+-------------+-----+
#|    0|     00:00:09|  AAB|
#|    0|     00:00:08|  AAB|
#|    0|     00:37:55|  AAB|
#|    0|     00:10:20|  AAB|
#|    0|     00:18:29|  AAB|
#|    0|     00:18:20|  AAB|
#|    0|     00:10:41|  AAB|
#|    0|     00:18:20|  AAB|
#|    0|     00:16:29|  AAB|
#|    0|     00:08:09|  AAB|
#|    0|     00:18:19|  AAB|
#|    0|     00:01:39|  AAB|
#|    1|         null|  RRE|
#|    1|         null|  RRE|
#|  234|         null|  ILL|
#|  452|         null|  INL|
#|11220|         null|  INL|
#|  100|         null|  AAB|
#|  122|         null|  AAB|
#|    0|     00:18:29|  BRQ|
#+-----+-------------+-----+
```